# matplot is missing from CRAN?

Tags: r, cran

Im taking an R programming class that is using the package "matplot" for a demo. I cant find "matplot" in CRAN so i'm assuming it has been replaced/deleted/changed. Is there another package that replaced it?

Comment: if you need the function `matplot` it is part of the graphics package which comes with base R. I'm not sure there was ever a "matplot" package

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`matplot`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.3.1/topics/matplot) function within the [`graphics`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.3.1) library. Here's an example from the documentation:

```
require(grDevices)
matplot((-4:5)^2, main = "Quadratic")
```

Also, [matplot](http://matplotlib.org/) is a plotting library for PHP. Perhaps your instructor could help clarify what is expected.